# Which directory to put the intent filtering file

Tags: android, security, android-intent

I have file with a set of intent filtering rules for android and want to integrate them into my custom android firmware. So the question is which directory I should put this file?

Comment: What are "intent filtering rules"?

Comment: I want to intercept android intents, especially i'm looking for an intent, that identifies some app is going to launch, then apply my rules and decide to launch it if it is safe, for example, or warn user - @CommonsWare

Comment: If you know some sources that can help me with this question, please advise